# Change internal links to external in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im working on a aplication witch gets its content from a different website. In the obtained content are sometimes internal links. I need to add the http://www.olddomain.com to the href value of those links, to make sure they will still work in my aplication.

The data is in a variable: text

variable text contains:

```
<p style="text-align: right;">
    Lots of text in here, with all kind of html tags, <br /><br /> 
    when suddenly a link appears:
    <a href="/niceinternalpage.html">Here!</a>
</p>
```

Output i need:

```
<p style="text-align: right;">
    Lots of text in here, with all kind of html tags, <br /><br /> 
    when suddenly a link appears:
    <a href="www.olddomain.com/niceinternalpage.html">Here!</a>
</p>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have both internal and external links, you can try a regex replace, like this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace(/^\/(.*)/, 'http://www.externaldomain.com/$1');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery to perform this operation in modern browsers, you can make use of `document.getElementsByTagName` to fetch all the `a` tags on the page:

```
// document.getElementsByTagName returns a `NodeList` - it looks like an `Array`
// but lacks all of the methods; so we use `Array.prototype.slice` to turn it
// into a 'real' `Array` so we can filter and loop over it.
aTags = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a")),
    externalUrl = "http://www.olddomain.com";

// Make use of `filter` to return an Array of all `a` tags whose `href` attribute
// is unqualified (eg: does not start with `http`, again you may wish to make this
// filtering logic more complex).
//
// We then chain a `forEach` call to the result of the `filter` call which prepends
// the `externalUrl` to the `a` tag's `href` attribute.
aTags
    .filter(function (aTag) { 
        return aTag.href.match(/^http/) === null;
    })
    .forEach(function(unqualifiedATag) { 
        var unqualifiedUrl = unqualifiedATag.href;

        // Add a leading forward slash.
        if (unqualifiedUrl.charAt(0) !== "/") {
            unqualifiedUrl = "/" + unqualifiedUrl;
        }

        // Update the aTag's href attribute to fully qualify it.
        unqualifiedATag.href = externalUrl + unqualifiedATag.href;
    });
```

Comment: +1 for plain javascript answer. This will however change ALL the a tags, which in most cases will not be the intent (links to facebook / twitter / etc will also get fetched, even navigation links in the same domain will)

Comment: Yep, that's a valid criticism ;)  The filter method should be updated to determine if the URL is qualified or not - let's do that now for fun...

Comment: document.links even works in pre-2000 browsers but filters and for each not in ie8

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to assign change the value of `href`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mF8XP/1/)**

```
$(variable).find('a').attr('href', function(idx, attrValue){ 
   return 'http://www.olddomain.com' + attrValue;
});
```

Comment: The second parameter is the current value of the attribute, not the item. So there's no need for `this.href`. But +1 for this rather elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var $content = $(text);
$content.find('a').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.olddomain.com' + $(this).attr('href') );
});
$content.insertAfter('#elementinyourpage');
```

I added also the call to insert your modified content into your current page.

Comment: Thanks for spotting there was an error, I've just fixed it, thank you.

Comment: `$(this).attr('href')` returns a value, you cannot assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var uri = $('a').attr('href');
$('a').attr('href', 'www.olddomain.com' + uri);
```

Hope it helps.